# How to mask Ubuntu as a Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

Is there an easy way to mask my Ubuntu laptop so it looks like a Chromebook?

Chromebooks are pretty common today, and I would prefer for sites not to know I was running a Ubuntu laptop.

Comment: I think you're looking for something that changes the browser "user agent"

Comment: Why not? Be proud that you're running Ubuntu! Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isn't really an Ubuntu answer but I am using a user agent masker in Chrome right now.

Google for the latest Chromebook user agent string and use this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg